# jQuery append function behaving async

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
$("#addr").append("<ul>");
$(data.customer).each( function() {
    $("#addr").append("<li><div><b><i><u>
                CUSTOMER ID </u></i></b>: "+this.custId+"<br>"+
            "<b><u>customer Phone</u></b>"+this.custPhone+"<br>");
    $("#addr").append("</div></li></br></br>");         
});

$("#addr").append("<p>hiiielajekf</p></ul>");
```

But in my browser, `<ul>` is empty, and all the list items start after `<ul></ul>`

Can anyone point out my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking in markup, but that's not what you're dealing with. You're dealing with an object tree. `$("#addr").append("<ul>")` creates and appends a `ul` element, it doesn't just *start* one. Similarly later where you have the `<li>...` in one `append` and a `</li>` in another, that's not how the DOM (and jQuery) work. Each individual string you pass into `append` has to be a complete, well-formed HTML snippet (with balanced start and end tags), with the exception that if you do just `.append("<tag>")`, jQuery treats it as though you did `.append("<tag></tag>")`.

Either build the whole thing up as a string and then append it all in one go, or work with the objects instead.

Doing a big string, assuming `data.customer` is an array (and that you need to stick to ES5-level features for some reason):

```
$("#addr").append(
    "<ul>" +
    data.customer.map(function(customer) {
        return "<li>" +
            "<div>" +
                "<b><i><u> CUSTOMER ID </u></i></b>: " +
                this.custId + "<br>" +
                "<b><u>customer Phone</u></b>: " +
                this.custPhone + "<br>"
            "</div>" +
        "</li>;
    }) +
    "</ul>"
);
$("#addr").append("<p>hiiielajekf</p></ul>");
```

or building each `li` separately:

```
var ul = $("<ul>");
data.customer.forEach(function(customer) {
    ul.append("<li>" +
            "<div>" +
                "<b><i><u> CUSTOMER ID </u></i></b>: " +
                this.custId + "<br>" +
                "<b><u>customer Phone</u></b>: " +
                this.custPhone + "<br>"
            "</div>" +
        "</li>");
});
$("#addr").append(ul);
$("#addr").append("<p>hiiielajekf</p></ul>");
```